# Center Button in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a 1-row form with email, name and submit button. The submit button should be centered in the remainder of the form. I tried margin:auto, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I have:
[image]
Here's what I would like to have:
[image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="well well-sm col-xs-8  col-xs-offset-2" style='background-color:#888; border-radius:5px;'>

    <form class="form">

    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4" style='margin:auto;'>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNpgNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need text-align: center in div

```
  <div class="col-xs-4" style='text-align:center;'>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
```